# Bash: test if a variable exists within another variable?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, wildcard

I have two variables, both are a list of filenames that have been moved by a script.

**Variable 1**:
Generated by a 'read' loop of a larger variable. At any given moment it only contains one filename.

> var1 = pic1.jpg
>
> var1 = pic2 duplicate.jpg
>
> var1 = pic3(dup).jpg
>
> var1 = pic4.jpg
>
> var1 = subfolder/subfolder picture.png

As shown above, the filenames can contain spaces, but do not always.

**Variable 2**: A string containing a list of files, each filename being separated by a `\n` newline character.

> var2 = pic1.jpg `\n` pic2 duplicate.jpg `\n` pic3(dup).jpg `\n` pic4.jpg

I am attempting to test if the contents of **var1** can be found in **var2**:

```
    listcontains() {
        for list_item in $1; do
            # Does $list_item exist in $2?
            if [[ "$list_item" =~ "$2" ]]; then
                return 0
            else
                return "1"
            fi
        done

    }

    # Call function to see if var1 is in var2
    if listcontains "$var1" "$var2"
       then
           # var1 is in var2; do stuff...
       else
           # Do different stuff...
   fi
```

This logic is clearly wrong, or the syntax is wrong, as it always returns a non-match at the moment:

```
does pic2 exist in pic2 duplicate.jpg
pic2.jpg
pic3(dup).jpg
pic3.jpg?
no

does pic3(dup).jpg exist in pic2 duplicate.jpg
pic2.jpg
pic3(dup).jpg
pic3.jpg?
no
```

I'm still learning bash, so if anybody could help me then it would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right-hand side of `=~` is the regex pattern. The left-hand side is the string to match it against.

You have your arguments backwards. You also aren't accounting for any regex special characters in `$list_item` which would throw off your matches.

Are your `$list_item` entries partial filenames or complete filenames? If they are complete filenames then it might be easier to use a `read` loop and do exact matches against each line in `$var2` instead of this (even better would beto use an associative array of filenames in `$var2` to make the matching much faster).

That being said using a string for filenames is a bad idea because it makes doing anything with them (especially if they can have spaces/etc.) difficult to impossible.

Comment: You are correct! I switched the arguments on the side of the test, and it fixed it to the output I expect.

The items are full filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Here I show you how it works in the console, you can then copy the code to a bash script file.

```
Frederick@Frederick-PC ~
$ for ele in "${var1[@]}"; do echo $ele; done
abc
def

Frederick@Frederick-PC ~
$ echo "$var2"
abc
ghi

Frederick@Frederick-PC ~
$ IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a array <<< "$var2"

Frederick@Frederick-PC ~
$ for ele in "${array[@]}"; do echo $ele; done
abc
ghi

Frederick@Frederick-PC ~
$ for ele in "${var1[@]}"; \
> do
> if [[ ${array[*]} =~ $ele ]]
> then
> echo "var2 contains $ele"
> else
> echo "var2 does not contain $ele"
> fi
> done
var2 contains abc
var2 does not contain def
```